# How to record audio from bluetooth headphones in flutter app

Tags: audio, flutter, dart, bluetooth, voice-recognition

I am trying to use the example found here

https://github.com/rxlabz/speech_recognition/tree/master/example

to translate audio into text speaking into my standard bluetooth headphones

https://www.walmart.com/ip/ONN-Bluetooth-In-Ear-Headphones-with-Micro-USB-Charging-Cable-Blue/202322980?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&wl13=1253&adid=22222222227000000000&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=42423897272&wl4=pla-51320962143&wl5=9028277&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=local&wl12=202322980&veh=sem&gclid=CjwKCAjw98rpBRAuEiwALmo-ysJrRm4Z4aXTLLgBN0VxSFLBr5Jo3NZCTyAGQFnd6r_yBULef45jVxoCsscQAvD_BwE

I know my headphones are paired and that the microphone works because I can make phone calls just fine, but I can't figure out how to make the app take the audio from headphones rather than using the microphone on my phone when recording.

Comment: Did you find out what happened? Stumbled upon the say problem.. :)

Comment: No :( I am also struggling with getting the button presses from the headset, while the volume buttons on the phone itself work just fine. Really unfortunate I can't figure out how to do this since almost everyone has these sorts of Bluetooth headphones these days.

Comment: Hi there, did you find anything? I'm trying to stream via phone mic but play only on headset/earbuds.... Because if I stream it's so much noise and crackling everywhere...